# Adding anchor line to a Bing Maps custom pushpin and allowing the user to drag

Tags: c#, silverlight, dictionary, bing-maps, pushpin

I am currently working on a Silverlight application using the Bing Map control, i am using a custom pushpin made up of an Image and a text block within a grid element, which works fine, this also allows me to have hover and right click events for each pushpin so all good so far, however there is a need for me to enable the user to drag the pushpin in any direction and have an a line connecting it to its actual position, sort of like an anchoring point.

I am struggling to see how to do this, I have seen lots of information on making the pushpins have the capability to be moved by the mouse but the line and anchor part is causing me a bit of a problem.  Currently i keep my pushpins in various Observable Collections so that when they are updated the UI updates.  If anyone has an Idea on a clean way of adding this functionality please let me know it will be much appreciated.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I haven't got time to knock up a complete example.  However I'll give away the basis of the solution.  Replace the template with one based on a `Canvas`.  For example you could have an ellipse to be the actual point on the map, a draggable border that has the ContentPresenter and a line to act as a tether.

The code needed is a) allow the Border to be dragged about and b) to move one end of the line about so that it lies under the Border.

Comment: Hi many thanks for the information, not sure i fully understand it though, I am fairly new to silverlight and WPF etc.. at the moment i have my own pushpin class inherited from a grid that simply has an image as one of its children, I set the map position on this, I am fairly confident i can make this draggable capturing the mouse interaction on this element however i am unsure how i would build your idea above into this setup?

Answer (score 0):

I am still interested in other approaches but I have come up with a solution of paring my pushpin  element with a MapPolyline, this in conjunction with the mouse handling to allow the user to drag the pushpin updates both, it is pretty effective and will do for now.  I would still like to hear from anyone else with better suggestions though.